# Unresolved reference: github, when trying to import Fuel library in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fuel

I am new to Kotlin so apologies if I am missing something simple here.

I am trying to import the Fuel libraries into my project, I have added the below into my Gradle which appears to sync fine

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:<latest-version>'
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:<package>:<latest-version>'
```

However, when I try to import this into my activity as below:

```
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result
```

'github' becomes highlighted in red, and the error below is shown:

```
Unresolved reference: github
```

As such I am unable to access the library, just wondering if I am missing something here in order to get this to work ? I have been able to import other libraries into my project successfully, so wondering if it is something specific to this implementation I am missing. Hoping somebody could kindly assist.

Comment: some error, i can find jar in cache, but it build failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are not using the dependencies you mentioned with the `<latest-version>` or `<package>` tags. These are meant to be replaced with actual version numbers/packages of the artifact, like this:

```
implementation "com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.3.1"
implementation "com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-coroutines:2.3.1"
```

If you don't have this issue, then I would recommend [invalidating Gradle caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html), restarting your IDE, and building from scratch for one more time. You can do that via the CLI too:

```sh
$ ./gradlew build
```